# How can I make an installer using Inno Setup?

Tags: java, inno-setup, launch4j

I have a new application jar file. It works perfect in my dist folder in the project folder. When I am trying to move this to another place it does not work for me.

For the solution of this problem I have created exe file using Launch4j in the dist folder and it also works in that folder only. I cannot move it to another folder.

For installer creation I am using Inno Setup builder. I create and install the application. But it also does not work for me. How can I make an installer using Inno Setup?

Comment: The answer for the question *"How can I make an installer using Inno Setup ?"* might be *"Pretty simply!"* or *"Take a look at the examples from your Examples folder of the InnoSetup installation."* ;-) In my opinion you should first find out how to deploy application with launch4j (especially how to configure paths, or if it's possible to distribute it and generate an *.exe ad-hoc from installer) and then take care of how to deploy it with InnoSetup. This question is too broad...

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug that is unrelated to installation. You need to modify your application code so that it can work in different directories.

Answer (score 1):

The pretty good way is to use [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html)  (Java Network Launch Protocol), all  sources  go to JVM. By this way you don't need any installation process.

*About your question* *"How can I make an installer using Inno Setup?"*

See below:

There is a lot of information how to create it.

All examples you can find in [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) that helped me to sort things out.

Here I'll give you example what I used and it worked for me:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApplicationName-O
AppVerName=MyApplicationName-O version 1.5.3.0
AppPublisher=myApplicationSite.com
AppPublisherURL=http://www.myApplicationSite.com
AppSupportURL=http://www.myApplicationSite.com
AppUpdatesURL=http://www.myApplicationSite.com
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApplicationName-O
DefaultGroupName=MyApplicationName-O
LicenseFile=COPYING
;InfoBeforeFile=README
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
ShowLanguageDialog=yes

UninstallDisplayIcon=C:\workspacePrototype\App\sources\myApplicationName\pixmaps\icon.ico
SetupIconFile=C:\workspacePrototype\App\sources\myApplicationName\pixmaps\icon.ico


[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"



[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
;;#include "myApplicationName-win32.filelist"
; DLL used to check if the target program is running at install time
Source: psvince.dll; flags: dontcopy
; psvince is installed in {app} folder, so it will be loaded at 
; uninstall time to check if the target program is running
Source: psvince.dll; DestDir: {app}
Source: ./bin/avcodec-53.dll; Destdir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: ./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0/Tabs/button_prelight.png; Destdir:    {app}\./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0/Tabs; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: ./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0/tooltip.png; Destdir:    {app}\./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: ./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0/trans.png; Destdir:    {app}\./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: ./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0/trough.png; Destdir:    {app}\./share/themes/Outcrop/gtk-2.0; Flags: ignoreversion
;Source: ./share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc; Destdir: {app}\./share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0; Flags: ignoreversion



[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApplicationName-O"; Filename: "{app}\MyApplicationName-O.exe" ; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userdesktop}\MyApplicationName-O"; Filename: "{app}\MyApplicationName-O.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}" ; Tasks: desktopicon

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip";
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip"; ValueData: "URL: SIP protocol" ; ValueType:string
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip"; ValueName: "EditFlags"; ValueData: "02 00 00 00" ; ValueType:binary
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip"; ValueName: "URL Protocol" ;  ValueType:string
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip\DefaultIcon"; ValueData: "{app}\MyApplicationName-O.exe"; ValueType:string ; Flags:uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip\shell"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip\shell\open"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "sip\shell\open\command"; ValueType:string ; ValueData: "{app}\MyApplicationName-O.exe --workdir {app} --call %1"; Flags:uninsdeletekey

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApplicationName-O.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,MyApplicationName-O}"; WorkingDir: "{app}" ; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

; Comment out the following two lines if you don't want a Start Menu program group
; to be created. (You'll need to run the uninstaller's EXE directly from its 
; folder (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Prompt to Close the Program") if you do.)

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Uninstall this application"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can run this script from Inno sSetup 5 or from command-line:

```
ISCC.exe myApplication.iss
Inno Setup 5 Command-Line Compiler
Copyright (C) 1997-2012 Jordan Russell. All rights reserved.
Portions Copyright (C) 2000-2012 Martijn Laan
Inno Setup Preprocessor
Copyright (C) 2001-2004 Alex Yackimoff. All rights reserved.

Compiler engine version: Inno Setup 5.5.2 (a)

[ISPP] Preprocessing.
[ISPP] Preprocessed.

Parsing [Setup] section, line 2
Parsing [Setup] section, line 3
Parsing [Setup] section, line 4
Parsing [Setup] section, line 5
Parsing [Setup] section, line 6
Parsing [Setup] section, line 7
Parsing [Setup] section, line 8
Parsing [Setup] section, line 9
Parsing [Setup] section, line 10
```

Comment: Well, but you have [`examples shipped with InnoSetup`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/tree/master/Examples)...

Comment: This is working script, actually its a bit bigger (with Pascal code, but it works)

Comment: Examples whose you have in the `Examples` folder of your InnoSetup installation also work... I have no idea, how the launch4j makes the *.jar file to be executable (how it internally finds runtime and whatever needed for its execution), but reading the second paragraph of the question makes me feel that OP is now fixed to a certain folder, which you can't rely on with serious installer. Hence my comment at the question. If I were OP, I would first find out how to configure launch4j (or how to use it to generate *.exe ad-hoc), to be independent on the source machine. And then make an installer.

Comment: You need write to registry component paths to make it work out of folder.

Comment: @TLama I would use JNLP technique to prevent any installation and dependence.

Comment: I don't know that either. What I'm still missing in your script is how you're writing to registry something related to launch4j executable to be independent... Now you're just registering your application as a default launcher for SIP protocol in Shell.